# Is it possible to reuse variables across LESS files?

Tags: less

If I have a .less file that imports two other .less files that both use and define the same variable name, the last definition in whichever file was imported last is the value used in all the other files. For example:

```
@import (less) ex1.less
@import (less) ex2.less
```

ex1.less:

```
@var: classname;

.@{var} {/*css*/}
```

ex2.less:

```
@var: classname2;

.@{var} {/*css*/}
```

generates:

```
.classname2 {/*css*/}
.classname2 {/*css*/}
```

I am not sure how to use namespaces here, so any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this question here, it may be usefull:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275829/less-css-change-variable-value-for-theme-colors-depending-on-body-class

Comment: Just put `&{}` around file content you want to isolate from any outer things. (For namespaces and related stuff in this context see for example [#2442](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2442)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much like CSS Less cascades it's values, so the last `var` declaration wins.

You only import one of the files.

Change the second `var`'s name.

Or make one of your less files more concise and use the `var` where needed.