# LESS CSS - Import inside Mixins not compiling

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, less

I am importing a less file inside Mixins but it is not compiled into the output. I am running command as `lessc client.less > client.css`. Below is my code.

**client.less:**

```
@color: #000;

@import "theme.less";

@import "dark-theme.less";

.themeDefs(1);
```

**theme.less:**

```
body {
   color: @color;
}
```

**dark-theme.less:**

```
.themeDefs(1) {
   @color: #fff;

   .darkTheme {
      @import "theme.less";
   }
}
```

**Output:**

```
body {
   color: #000;
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
body {
   color: #000;
}

.darkTheme body {
   color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By referring this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15279979/4131978), I am able to achieve this by using loop in [less css](http://lesscss.org/).

Comment: If you think this is a duplicate Question, please flag it to be closed as a duplicate. If not add context to any links so your answer is self contained, see ["Provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).