# Defining Less variable depending on body class

Tags: themes, less, global-variables

I'd like to define a **global** LESS variable depending on a class that is applied to the `<body>`.

Is this possible with LESS?

Here is my mixin:

```
.dynamic-colors(@color) {

    //set my variable
    @c-dynamic: @color;

    //I can use my variable here
    .something {
        color: @c-dynamic;
    }
}

body.colors--black {
    .dynamic-colors(#000000);
}

body.colors--red {
    .dynamic-colors(#ff0000);
}

.something-else {
    //this returns undefined because @c-dynamic
    //was only defined inside of .dynamic-colors()
    color: @c-dynamic;
}
```

I believe `@c-dynamic` will be limited to the scope of the `.dynamic-colors` mixin.

Is there any way I can set the variable to be global?

Comment: Well, no, it can't work that way. Less code is compiled with no knowledge of your HTML so you can't use a HTML stuff ("body class") as a *condition* for variable values. In other words if you want `.something-else` to have different colors to apply depending on different body classes you also need to define multiple `.something-else` rulesets (e.g. `.colors--black .something-else`, `.colors--red .something-else` etc.).

Comment: Or yet in another words, note that in your snippet its *two* `@c-dynamic` variables defined unconditionally. So if you make them global only one of them (the last one) will have an effect regardless of body class in HTML.

Comment: For possible approaches see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15368587 and similar Q/A found with http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bless%5d%20theme

Answer (score 1):

So to not leave this one without an answer. You can define global variable with a mixin just by invoking that mixin in the global scope, e.g.:

```
.dynamic-colors(@color) {
    @c-dynamic: @color;
}

.dynamic-colors(#123); // expose @c-dynamic into global scope

div {
   color: @c-dynamic; // -> #123
}
```

**But** (as mentioned in comments above) this does not look like something you really mean to get in the end. You **can't** make this (or any other) variable value to depend on a `body` class since at the time of compilation Less has no knowledge of the HTML you're going to apply the generated CSS to.