# Dynamic body class with less

Tags: html, css, less

Is there a way to dynamically pick between the two colors below based on a class on the body without adding the body class to every less snippet that contains the color using less?

```
@basketballColor: #ff9900;
@footballColor: #99743d;
```

**Can we do this?**

```
.navbar-inner {
    background-color: @mainColor;
 }
```

**I know we can do this but would like to condense it**

```
body.basketball {

            .navbar-inner {
                background-color: @basketballColor;
            }
        }

body.football {

            .navbar-inner {
                background-color: @footballColor;
            }
        }
```

Comment: No, I don't think it is possible to dynamically assign color based on the `class` assigned to the `body` (or any tag for that matter). Second option (or writing a loop) would be the better choice.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible (maybe with the JavaScript version). You could look into this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15368587/3695983.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite often asked here at SO:

- [LESS condition based on CSS class to set a LESS variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366576)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25877100
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23553422

Just condense it via [mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature), it is as simple as:

```
// usage:

body {
    .navbar(basketball, #ff9900);
    .navbar(football,   #99743d);
}

// impl:

.navbar(@name, @color) {
    &.@{name} .navbar-inner {
        background-color: @color;
    }
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
// usage:

.navbar(basketball, #ff9900);
.navbar(football,   #99743d);

// impl:

.navbar(@name, @color) {
    body.@{name} .navbar-inner {
        background-color: @color;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or maybe call them within a loop if in case there are more such class-color combinations.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Just to point out that in `body.@{name}` you do need to ADD curly braces around `name` to get the text from `@name` otherwise it would not work. I spent a few minutes here till I realised the issue I had.