# How to use different values for LESS CSS variables depending on CSS selector?

Tags: css, less

Suppose you want to use multiple color schemes for different sections of a site. Static elements like header & navigation should use a variation of a given color (using [less color functions](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations)).
Each section has the theme name attached as a `class` on the body. So you could think of something like this:

```
body {
    &.red {
        @col: #f00;
    }
    &.blue {
        @col: #00f;
    }

    background-color:darken(@col, 5%);
    color:lighten(@col, 20%);

    // & children
}
```

But `@col` is not available outside of `.red` or `.blue`: `NameError: variable @col is undefined`

*Is it possible to define a variable depending on a css selector?
If not, what else could be done?*

Edit: Sorry, this is a duplicate of [Defining Variable Variables using LESS CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198221/defining-variable-variables-using-less-css?rq=1)

Comment: I don't think variables exist right now, but it looks like they could be coming: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/

Comment: I am using [less](http://lesscss.org), should've been more clear about that!

Comment: To answer the question: no, it's not. You need to do it in reverse. For example see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15368587/2712740, http://stackoverflow.com/q/23551080/2712740 etc. (there're wide variations, more results can be found by searching for "theme" and "theming"). And I can't see how the A you linked above as a duplicate can help you (it very different use-case).